# How to concatenate words that starts and end with a vowel?

Tags: java

I receive a list of words and assigns them to write all the words that start and end with a vowel.
I need to write a MasinaDeTeme class that contains a public Word filtering method.
The method will receive as a parameter a string of String (String []) and will return a StringBuffer that will contain all the words with the required property concatenated in the order in which they appear in the string.

Here is the part of my cod where is my problem:

```
public static StringBuffer filtrareCuvinte(String[] cuvinte){
   
    for(int i = 0; i < cuvinte.length; i++)

        if(isVowel(cuvinte[i].charAt(0)) && isVowel(cuvinte[i].charAt(cuvinte.length - 1)))
            s.append(cuvinte[i]);

    return s;
}
```

}

I receive an error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

I think its because of the length. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think the strings contained in the array `cuvinte` have the same length as that array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you in your second call are using the length of the String[] that is passed to the *filtrareCuvinte* method.

Instead use the following:

```
public static StringBuffer filtrareCuvinte(String[] cuvinte){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < cuvinte.length; i++){
        if(isVowel(cuvinte[i].charAt(0)) && isVowel(cuvinte[i].charAt(cuvinte[i].length() - 1)))
            sb.append(cuvinte[i] + " ");
    }

    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check the character at the last index of the word, but you search for the last index of words array. Try this:

```
public static StringBuffer filtrareCuvinte(String[] cuvinte){

    for(String word : cuvinte)
    {
        if(isVowel(word.charAt(0)) && 
              isVowel(word.charAt(word.length - 1)))
        s.append(cuvinte[i]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second `isVovwel` condition is breaking at `charAt` call; Simply change  below inside for loop,

```
 if(isVowel(cuvinte[i].charAt(0)) && isVowel(cuvinte[i].charAt(cuvinte[i].lenght-1)))
                s.append(cuvinte[i]);
```